# Get all column names of a DataTable into string array using (LINQ/Predicate)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I know we can easily do this by a simple loop, but I want to persue this LINQ/Predicate?

```
string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.?

or

string[] columnNames = from DataColumn dc in dt.Columns select dc.name;
```

Answer (score 280, accepted):

Try this (LINQ method syntax):

```
string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                 .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                                 .ToArray();
```

or in LINQ Query syntax:

```
string[] columnNames = (from dc in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                        select dc.ColumnName).ToArray();
```

`Cast` is required, because Columns is of type DataColumnCollection which is a `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<DataColumn>`. The other parts should be obvious.

Comment: i am a newbie in linq/lamda ex. This looks good. one more question, how can i place condation(where dc.ColumnName != "ABC") in 1 lamda expression. in linq i can use where.

Comment: Just like this:  
`string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(x => x.ColumnName != "ABC").Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray();`

Comment: I still get 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' to type 'System.Data.DataColumn'.  What is going on?

Comment: @Tizz: Please post it as a new question and include details of your code. But essentially: A DataGrid is not the same as a DataTable.

Comment: if you put the former snippet in a for each loop, will it do all that casting for each item? `foreach(string item in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x=>x.ColumnName).ToArray()) { ... }`

Comment: This has syntax error. I guess because you have used a specific assembly. Please add using part in your answer when you use special things

Comment: @FLICKER: Some thinking is still required as a developer. You have a brain. Use it.

Comment: Ah well. Just look at the votes. Obviously, the problem is with you, not with the code. Go troll somewhere else

Answer (score 19):

Use

```
var arrayNames = (from DataColumn x 
                  in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                  select x.ColumnName).ToArray();
```

Comment: On my end, this throws two Exceptions: cannot convert from DataColumnCollection to EnumerableRowCollection and DataColumnCollection does not contain a definition for Cast.

Comment: @Jon I think you forogot to add 'using System.Linq;' to your usings. I just tested my code and I get the exceptions you mention when 'using System.Linq;' isn't there.

Comment: Doh!  You are quite correct; funny, that `using` statement is automatically added so often, it never occurred to me to check for it.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest using such extension method:

```
public static class DataColumnCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<DataColumn> AsEnumerable(this DataColumnCollection source)
    {
        return source.Cast<DataColumn>();
    }
}
```

And therefore:

```
string[] columnNames = dataTable.Columns.AsEnumerable().Select(column => column.Name).ToArray();
```

You may also implement one more extension method for `DataTable` class to reduce code:

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<DataColumn> GetColumns(this DataTable source)
    {
        return source.Columns.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
string[] columnNames = dataTable.GetColumns().Select(column => column.Name).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<String> lsColumns = new List<string>();

if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
{
    var count = dt.Rows[0].Table.Columns.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count;i++ )
    {
        lsColumns.Add(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0][i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes [a perfect solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5026354/861716) worse and unintelligible.